# Install fonts to PC using Inno Setup

Tags: fonts, inno-setup, windows

I created a Windows application and that uses a particular font. So I need to install that font to the users system using Inno Setup.

I used this code:

```
Source: "ARLRDBD.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Oz Handicraft BT"; \
    Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

But this code had no effect when I tested it in my system.

How can I do it perfectly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`FontInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) - This must be **exactly the same name** as you see when you double-click the font file in Explorer. In your case you have left the name from the Inno Setup's Help Example.

> Source: "ARLRDBD.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "**Oz
>   Handicraft BT**"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall

**Oz Handicraft BT** is not the real name of **ARLRDBD.TTF** font.

The real `FontInstall` value for **ARLRDBD.TTF** is `Arial Rounded MT Bold`

Comment: I tried it too , but Arial Rounded MT font is not installed in the test system

Comment: It has to be `Arial Rounded MT Bold` not `Arial Rounded MT`. And you have to run Setup either as an `Administrator` or `Power User`. All is pointed in the Inno Help Doc.

Comment: Yeah it is working .... Actually in my previous comment I left "Bold" , but in the script I have given it correctly . Finally I found that the problem ins not with the script and it is with the .tff file I am using