# Installing fonts with my application using C#

Tags: inno-setup

I am developing a project in C# where I need digital-7 font. Previously I have used InnoSetup for making my C# application files to setup files which could be install in any PC. I have never modified InnoSetup code.

I found this Link but I didn't understand anything. Somehow I tried a demo software where I added my font files like this

```
Source: "C:\Users\DEVJEET MANDAL\Downloads\digital-7\digital-7 (italic).ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "digital-7"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\DEVJEET MANDAL\Downloads\digital-7\digital-7 (mono italic).ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "digital-7"; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "C:\Users\DEVJEET MANDAL\Downloads\digital-7\digital-7 (mono).ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "digital-7"; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "C:\Users\DEVJEET MANDAL\Downloads\digital-7\digital-7.ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "digital-7"; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "C:\Users\DEVJEET MANDAL\Downloads\digital-7\readme.txt"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "digital-7"; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

While installing I get this error

> ADD FONT RESOURCE FAILED

I am totally new to this. Can anyone give some insight about this?

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: Add the fonts as a resource to your setup and copy them to the windows fonts directory

Comment: I removed your c# tag because it is not related to the issue. Your problam has to do with your script and how you are trying to install the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider making use of [Inno Script Studio](https://www.innoscriptstudio.com/) for this issue.

Select **Install Fonts...** from the **Project** menu:

[image]

Then, select your fonts. For example:

[image]

The file(s) get added to the script for you at the location of the cursor. This should be in the `[Files]` section of your script. For example:

```
Source: "C:\Windows\Fonts\digital-7 (italic).ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Digital-7 Italic"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "C:\Windows\Fonts\digital-7 (mono italic).ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Digital-7 MonoItalic"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "C:\Windows\Fonts\digital-7 (mono).ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Digital-7 Mono"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "C:\Windows\Fonts\digital-7.ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Digital-7"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

It will get the `FontInstall` parameter correct which is your problem. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186646/install-fonts-to-pc-using-inno-setup) for reference.

You have given them all the same `FontInstall` value which is wrong. To quote the [help](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm):

> Tells Setup the file is a font that needs to be installed. The value of this parameter is the name of the font as stored in the registry or WIN.INI. **This must be exactly the same name as you see when you double-click the font file in Explorer**. Note that Setup will automatically append " (TrueType)" to the end of the name.